# Как сделать специфическую подложку текста?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как сделать специфическую подложку текста, как на картинке, не меняя HTML, то есть, чтобы текст был одним тегом без переносов?

[image: картинка]

Вот что у меня получилось, но правильно работает только в хроме. в мозилле и сафари глючит

```css
.blog__title{
  width: 220px;
}
.blog__title a {
  color: #004ec8;
  background: #f7e568;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: inline;
  padding: 2px 5px 4px 10px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 28px;
}
.blog__title a:after {
  content: "";
  width: 35px;
  height: 25px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #f7e568 50%, transparent 50%);
  display: inherit;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: -32px;
  left: inherit;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog__title">
<a href="#">Дежурство скорой помощи на мероприятиях</a>
</div>
```

Comment: "глючит" - что это значит? Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: вот  скрин с хрома - http://joxi.ru/krDY1z7u4JWegm скрин с мозиллы - https://ibb.co/yfsC56W и скрин с safari - http://joxi.ru/DrlZ7gETy057Z2

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #e8f1ff;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  color: #004fc8;
  background: #f7e569;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .1rem;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text:last-of-type {
padding-right: 3rem;
}

.text:last-of-type:after{
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #c5dcfe;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: -3rem;
}

.bg-right {
  position: absolute;
  background: #c5dcfe;
  height: 400%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-55deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bg-right"></div>
  <div class="text">Дежурство скорой помощи</div>
  <br>
  <div class="text">на мероприятиях</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Так не пойдет, нужно чтобы заголовок был в однов блоке, без разрывов. То есть, не меняя HTML

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вариант, с использованием `linear-gradient`

```css
.text-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(115deg, #e8f1ff 50%, #c5dcfe calc(50% + .5px));
  color: #004fc8;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Roboto,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,"Noto Sans Armenian","Noto Sans Bengali","Noto Sans Cherokee","Noto Sans Devanagari","Noto Sans Ethiopic","Noto Sans Georgian","Noto Sans Hebrew","Noto Sans Kannada","Noto Sans Khmer","Noto Sans Lao","Noto Sans Osmanya","Noto Sans Tamil","Noto Sans Telugu","Noto Sans Thai",sans-serif;
}

.text-wrapper > p {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #f7e569;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text-wrapper > p:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.text-wrapper > p:last-child {
  max-width: calc(100% - 1.5rem);
  position: relative;
}

.text-wrapper > p:last-child::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #f7e569 50%, transparent calc(50% + .5px));
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-wrapper">
  <p>Дежурство скорой помощи</p><br>
  <p>на мероприятиях</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Так не пойдет, нужно чтобы заголовок был в однов блоке, без разрывов. То есть, не меняя HTML Но и так криво отображается